# Circularly shifting array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have the array like below in code snippet. My requirement is to start array from any key as the input specified . Input will be the key of array.
So if input is 0 then output will be  `[{a:10},{b:20},{c:30},{d:40}];`
and if input is 1 then output will be `[{{b:20},{c:30},{d:40},{a:10}];`

I tried to map array twice and merge them but ended with un-necessary empty array. Any help will be appreciated

```js
let arr=[{a:10},{b:20},{c:30},{d:40}];
let n=1
let s=arr.map((a,i)=>{return i>=n ? a : ''});
let s1=arr.map((a,i)=>{return i<n ? a : ''});
let shifted=s.concat(s1);
console.log(shifted);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can splice and merge them using spread operator

```js
let arr=[{a:10},{b:20},{c:30},{d:40}];

const shift=start=>{
   let arr1=arr.slice();
   return [...arr1.splice(start, arr1.length),...arr1.splice(0,start)]
}

console.log(shift(1));
console.log(shift(2));
console.log(shift(3));
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to `.map`, since your output arrays contain the same elements as the input arrays - instead, use `slice` to separate the two chunks, and then rearrange:

```js
let arr=[{a:10},{b:20},{c:30},{d:40}];
let n=1
const output = arr.slice(n).concat(arr.slice(0, n));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough (take from front and put it to back n-times):

```js
let arr=[{a:10},{b:20},{c:30},{d:40}];
let n = 2;
for(let i=0; i < n; i++) arr.push(arr.shift())
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this using `Array.slice` (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)). For example:

```js
(() => {
  const a = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
  const reshuffle = index => a.slice(index).concat(a.slice(0, index));
  let i = 0;
  while(i++ < a.length) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(reshuffle(i)));
  }
})();
```